# scaffolded controller actions

Tags: grails

I'm looking at the controller which has been generated using `grails generate-all`. Is there a reason why there are both `create` and `save` actions? It would make more sense to me to have only `create` as an action and `save` as a service. Something like this:

```
def create = {
    if (params.create) { //this is the save button
         if (!domainService.save(params)) {
             render(view: "create", model: [domain: new Domain(params)]) //show validation errors
         }
         else {
             render(view: "show", id: params.id)
         }
    }
    else {
        render(view: "create") //show blank form
    }
}
```

Are there any reasons why I should keep both `create` and `save` actions and not go down this path? The scaffolded controller is too heavy in my oppinion and I'm looking for ways to make it a bit more consise (I'm using the scaffolded code to learn grails from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create action is first-time entry for creating new Domain instance, while save is a simple action which tries to save. These action have clear names and simple code in controller.

Your approach has some problems though. You have two levels of if-else - it can be problematic and it's not so easy to read and maintain. You need to create and maintain domainService that does controller job in fact. There is no need to split simple save() to service.

As for me default generated grails controller is much simpler than yours.